# Why can't I modify the property js animate() applies to an element?

Tags: javascript, html

After the animation finishes, the click event will no longer work, in fact, changing the value from the dev tools will not work either. Using `fill: 'none'` will work, but I want to use the styling applied by the animation.

Is this expected behaviour ? The animation finishes and applies the style to the element as an inline `style` (or does it?), why can't it be modified in this case ? Is there a way to keep the style that the animation applies and then modify it?

*Example: event listener no longer works after animation finished*

```js
let square = document.querySelector('.circle')

square.addEventListener('click', () => {
    square.style.transform = 'translateY(50px)'
})

let animation = [
    {transform: 'translateY(100px)'}
]

square.animate(animation, {duration: 2000, fill: 'both'})
```

```css
.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #c965a6;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class='circle'></div>
```

**Edit: Found a solution**

Use `fill: 'none'`, listen for when the animation finishes and manually apply the final styling to the element.

```
let anim = square.animate(animation, {duration: 2000, fill: 'none'})
anim.addEventListener('finish', () => {
  square.style.transform = 'translateX(0px)'
})
```

Though this seems more like an workaround, I'd still like to know why you can't modify properties applied by an animation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply how the Web Animations API (WAAPI) is intended to function. Styles applied by the API take precedence over all other css styles, even inline styles, unless `important` is applied.
See the section "[Combining effects](https://www.w3.org/TR/web-animations-1/#combining-effects)" of the specs.
(The API does not, by the way, change the style attribute, but applies the styles in the WAAPI context. You can get the styles applied by the Animations API by calling`el.getAnimations()`.)

There are two ways you can apply styles after a WAAPI style is applied:

1. Use `important`, like this:

`square.style.setProperty( 'transform', 'translateY(0px)', 'important' );`

2. Cancel the whole animation and then apply a style: `anim.cancel();`

```js
let square = document.querySelector('.circle');
let anim;
square.style.transform = 'translateY(50px)';
square.addEventListener('click', () => {
    anim.cancel();
    square.style.transform = 'translateY(0px)';
});
let animation = [
    {transform: 'translateY(100px)'}
];
anim = square.animate(animation, {duration: 2000, fill: 'both'});
```

```css
.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #c965a6;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class='circle' ></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can [`cancel()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation/cancel) your Animation, so that its effects are removed.

```js
// Beware I renamed your variables so they match better (except for the triangle of course :P)
const square = document.querySelector('.circle')

const keyframes = [
    {transform: 'translateY(100px)'}
]

const animation = square.animate(keyframes, {duration: 2000, fill: 'both'})

square.addEventListener('click', () => {
    animation.cancel();
    square.style.transform = 'translateY(50px)'
})
```

```css
.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #c965a6;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class='circle'></div>
```